# pyspark and python package performance

Tags: python, pyspark, anaconda

I've been using pyspark for work for about a year now and I'm wondering if anyone has any resources to help explain what goes on in the background when someone uses, say, Pandas from an anaconda install. For example, if I'm loading data into a pandas df with the read_csv method, I'm assuming this is NOT a distributed task, right? Likewise, are any python packages you import and use on pyspark also not distributed? Again, I'm inexperienced with the "guts" of how spark works like this, so I apologize for any bad phrasing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I'm loading data into a pandas df with the read_csv method, I'm assuming this is NOT a distributed task, right?

Right

> Likewise, are any python packages you import and use on pyspark also not distributed?

Indeed they are not.

Pyspark does not change at all the behavior of any other packages you may happen to use. Practically speaking, it is *kind of* another Python package (nowadays it is even [available in PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyspark/2.2.0)); the distributed part kicks off only when you start transferring data to its own structures (RDDs, Spark dataframes etc), and even then it depends on how exactly you run the script (e.g. running in local mode will not distribute anything).

> I'm wondering if anyone has any resources to help explain what goes on in the background when someone uses, say, Pandas from an anaconda install

It should be clear by now that there are not any resources on this, simply because there is nothing *specific* going on when you use pandas (or numpy, or scikit-learn...) in a Pyspark script.

Comment: That's good confirmation, thank you! So then I'm going to assume it's always a better idea to NOT use python packages in pyspark whenever possible if you want to reap the performance benefits of large datasets on spark. Appreciate the clarity!

Comment: @kemri Loosely speaking: either your data fits into main memory, in which case you have *absolutely no reason to use Spark*, or they don't, in which case you generally *cannot* use standard packages like pandas or scikit-learn. That said, there will be cases where packages like numpy are indeed useful & necessary...